# How to reload a Partial View while also creating new Row in DB without getting redirected

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views

I am stuck on a problem where I am trying to reload a partial view while also creating a new row in the DB. 
I have a parent view which contains two partial views. One is a list of all questions and the other one is to create new questions. 
After creating a new question I want to reload the list partial view while not getting redirected away from the parent view.
I managed to load the list partial view (not sure if it also gets reloaded), but I keep getting redirected. 
I know that's because the create method in the controller returns a view, but I am not sure how to rewrite the method so it doesn't redirect to a different view.

**The part of the partial view in which a new question is created looks like this:**

```
<form id="form" asp-action="Create">
   <div class="form-group">
     <input id="testId" type="hidden" asp-for="Tests_TestID" value="@ViewData["Test_ID"]">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="Punkte_PunkteID" class="control-label"></label>
      <select id="punkteId" asp-for="Punkte_PunkteID" class="form-control" asp- 
       items="ViewBag.Punkte_PunkteID"> 
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <button id="createButton" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
   </div>
</form>
```

```
<script>
 document.getElementById("createButton").onclick = function ()
 {
        $.ajax( {
            url: "/../fragen/Index",
            type: "GET",
        })
           .done(function (partialViewResult) {
                $("#questionList").html(partialViewResult);
           });
  };
</script>
```

"#questionList" is the Partial View which contains a List of all questions.

After clicking the createButton the question should be created and the other partial view in the parent view should be reloaded.

**The Post create method in the Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Tests_TestID,Punkte_PunkteID")] Question question)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         fragen.Fragen_ID = _fragenService.getNextVal();
         await _questionService.CreateAsync(question);
         return new EmptyResult();
     }
     ViewData["Punkte_PunkteID"] = new SelectList(await _punkteService.getAllAsync(), "Punkte_ID", "Punkte_ID", questions.Punkte_PunkteID);
     return View(questions);
     //return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Do I have to use Ajax for both the creation of the question and the reload of the partial view?

Answer (score 0):

You should submit the form with ajax. And in the Post Create Action, you should redirect to the action which return the partial view of list questions. Then in the ajax call back function, replace the questionList with the returned partial view.